# How to run command at startup in linux?

Tags: linux, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash Script on Startup? (Linux)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/bash-script-on-startup-linux)

I want to run some commands at boot time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash Script on Startup? (Linux)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/bash-script-on-startup-linux); see also [Create services in Linux (Start up in linux)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1924/create-services-in-linux-start-up-in-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Use `/etc/rc.local`

On my system, the comment header says this:

```
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.
```

Comment: This is for Debian and Debian-derived distributions such as Ubuntu.  Other distros might be different.

Comment: It works on CentOS/RHEL as well.